# mongo eval not evaluating eval expression given through env variable

Tags: bash, mongodb, environment-variables, eval, mongo-shell

I'm trying to make a "wrapper" bash alias function to evaluate mongo snippets

```
alias mongoshelleval=mongoshelleval
mongoshelleval(){
    mongo --verbose --eval $1 $db
    }
```

And I have the snippets stored as env variables

```
export delsessions='"db.sessions.drop()"'
```

The I execute the thing

```
mongoshelleval $delsessions
```

but it doesn't carry out the operation. It just

> $ mongoshelleval $delsessions
>       MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
>       Thu Aug 07 03:50:18.809 versionArrayTest passed
>       connecting to: db
>       Thu Aug 07 03:50:18.861 creating new connection to:127.0.0.1:27017
>       Thu Aug 07 03:50:18.867 BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
>       Thu Aug 07 03:50:18.870 connected connection!
>       db.sessions.drop()
>       Thu Aug 07 03:50:18.880 freeing 1 uncollected class     mongo::DBClientWithCommands objects

Without throwing any errors. Just prints back the argument `db.sessions.drop()`

And the sessions are still there

> $ mongoshell
>       MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
>       connecting to: db
>   db.sessions.find()
>       { "_id" : "yr5rxguSbb32Q880Jj36Rq2_uU
>       { "_id" : "9PQh_ml5Gloiaunv6pbgVevM_6
>       { "_id" : "OacGUyf-V1DcTQIg3lMgFXUL-N
>       { "_id" : "GC7gh09iqVUny9HM8gnGl9Hzxt
>       { "_id" : "_f4koE0tagJ7vwuU76BatcDeEb
>       { "_id" : "t1CX_eqi7FcCREfBB2X5CpgOcz

Why doesn't it do what I intend it to do, and why isn't it throwing any errors if it's not carrying out the query?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra pair of quotes. Try

```
export delsessions="db.sessions.drop()"
```

For example, the following works for me

```
mongo> db.sessions.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53e5078d5b8b40be16223165"), "a" : 1 }
mongo> exit
bye

bash$ export test="db.sessions.drop()"
bash$ mongo --eval $test
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3
connecting to: test
true
bash$ mongo

mongo> db.sessions.find()
// nothing
```

I augmented my > and $ prompts with whether I was in the mongo shell or the bash shell, for extra clarity.